# More elegant way of comparing objects in Java

Tags: java, guava, apache-commons

Java has an inteface `Comparator<T>`, that has a method `int compare(T o1, T o2)`.

EDIT:

I was wrong with this:

> The returned integer must be `-1` if the first object is less than
>   second one, `1` if second one is less than first one, `0` if they're
>   equal.

Docs state:

> a negative integer, zero, or a positive integer as the first argument
>   is less than, equal to, or greater than the second.

So I rephrase my question: 
Is there a more elegant way of comparing objects, than bearing in mind that `comparator.compare(o1, o2) < 0` actually means that first object is less than second one?

Comment: Matter of 3 constants. Can't you just declare them in any Util file ?

Comment: Why don't you declare them yourself?

Comment: You can use Guava's [Ordering](https://github.com/google/guava/wiki/OrderingExplained).

Comment: The return value is neither 1 nor -1 is case of non equal integer.
The return value is positive number or negative number. 
There is no constants from 'positive' numbers nor 'negative'..

Comment: The question is justified. "Magic numbers" -1, 0, 1 should be defined somewhere in the Java standard library, but it appears that they are not.

Answer (score 5):

Compare your statement

> The returned integer must be -1 if the first object is less than second one, 1 if second one is less than first one, 0 if they're equal.

with the official statement

> Returns a negative integer, zero, or a positive integer as the first argument is less than, equal to, or greater than the second.

and note that the only appropriate constant is zero.

Answer (score -1):

The official interface contract for compare method is:

> Returns a negative integer, zero, or a positive integer as the first
>   argument is less than, equal to, or greater than the second.

While in fact all you need is three values, this logic can be used to write elegant code like this:

```
public int compare(MyObject o1, MyObject o2){
    return o1.getIntValue() - o2.getIntValue();
}
```

Which in one line not only gives you which object is greater (or equal), it even gives you how much one is greater than the other.

(Integer overflows not considered.)

Comment: Java has provided `Integer.compare` so users never again need to go through this. Also note that OP is comparing _objects_, not integers.

Comment: It's not elegant because it's buggy. You wrote that it's buggy, but this doesn't make it any better. You can never know what values such a method gets called with, so you'd better avoid overflow, especially when it's that simple.